# Chip Genius for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, usb-drive

Do we have something like Chip Genius software to reset the USB drive? I have few USB sticks which are having some read only error. I tried fixing it with Gparted, Disks utility and a few other tools too but no luck. If there is chip genius software for Ubuntu or any other alternative tools then kindly let me know.